# How to search message in mailbox with net/imap in Ruby?

Tags: ruby, search, imap

I have some script on Ruby 1.9.3:

```
require "net/imap"
imap = Net::IMAP.new(mail_imap_server)
imap.login(mail_login, mail_password)
imap.select("INBOX")
puts imap.search(["FROM", "homer@simpson.com"])
imap.logout
imap.disconnect
```

If the desired message is present, then all is well.
If the desired message is missing, an error:

```
/opt/local/lib/ruby1.9/1.9.1/net/imap.rb:1332:in `block in search_internal': undefined method `[]' for nil:NilClass (NoMethodError)
from /opt/local/lib/ruby1.9/1.9.1/monitor.rb:211:in `mon_synchronize'
from /opt/local/lib/ruby1.9/1.9.1/net/imap.rb:1326:in `search_internal'
from /opt/local/lib/ruby1.9/1.9.1/net/imap.rb:752:in `search'
from ./mail.rb:12:in `mail'
from ./mail.rb:26:in `<main>'
```

How can I solve this problem?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

first check if there are messages in the result, use a rescue just in case

```
require "net/imap" 
imap = Net::IMAP.new(mail_imap_server) 
imap.login(mail_login, mail_password) 
imap.select("INBOX")
begin
  messages = imap.search(["FROM", "homer@simpson.com"]) 
  puts messages if messages.length > 0
rescue
  puts "Error while retrieving the message" 
end
imap.logout 
imap.disconnect
```